# Cannot Start KVM VM Because Missing BIOS

Tags: kvm, qemu

Whenever I attempt to start a KVM virtual machine on Ubuntu 14.04 with the `kvm` command, I get the following error:

```
qemu: could not load PC BIOS 'bios-256k.bin'
```

I have searched for this file and found it exists in the `/usr/share/qemu` directory as a symlink to `../seabios/bios-256k.bin`. When I attempt to view the contents of that directory with `ls`, the system says that there is no such file or directory. However, I can `cd` to that directory and view the BIOS file. When I type `ls ..` from the `qemu` directory, the only item that is returned is `qemu`. I'm logged in as root, so I should be able to see all of the folders in `/usr/share`. Does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: Maybe try reinstalling? https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/seabios

Comment: I apt-get purge'd and re-installed all the packages and I still get the same error. I think it might be a permissions error? I don't know how that's possible though as I'm root.

Comment: I think I might have fixed it! However, the solution is really weird. What I did was delete the old symbolic link and create a new one with an absolute instead of a relative path. I had to do this for a few other files as well.

Comment: Well, that's good - and bad. Play around with `ls -l` in that area. If your colors are setup like mine bad links will standout in red.

Comment: I would use `virsh` and stop/start your KVM instances with that.

Comment: The reason I'm using qemu-system-x86_64 is that I'm trying to get a ConVirt appliance running.

Comment: I dunno if this would be of any use to you, but when I run `qemu` I usually use a variant of the linked text file. The `${leading_vars}` are parameters - to enable them you do, like `qxl= _qemu` - it's been awhile since I ran this,  but it worked when I last did. http://gdriv.es/mikeserv/scripts/qemu_sample.txt

Answer (score 9):

```
yum install seabios
```

worked for me

Comment: On CentOS, it's "yum install seabios-bin" for the same issue.  For some reason qemu packages make symlinks to files installed by seabios-bin RPM, but don't declare a dependency

Answer (score 5):

Including `-L /path/to/bios` in the arguments(as stated below. However you won't need the first step) will make Qemu look in the specified directory for the bios.

So it'd be: `qemu-system-x86_64 -L /usr/share/qemu/` along with the rest of the arguments. This means you won't have to change the symbolic link.

[Source](https://techglimpse.com/qemu-system-x86-command-error-solution/)

Answer (score 0):

For Centos 7 the file itself was missing (with broken symlinks) from `seabios`. I found that `xen-runtime` provided `bios-256k.bin` with `yum whatprovides '*/bios-256k.bin'`
 however the package had conflicting files with (unimportant) qemu files. These are the following steps I needed to make qemu work:

```
yum install --downloadonly xen-runtime --downloaddir=.
rpm -i --replacefiles xen-hypervisor* xen-runtime*
qemu-system-x86_64 -L /usr/share/qemu-xen/qemu <your args>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that on Centos 7 when installing XEN (want to keep it), then seabios-bin provided by xen repo do not have seabios-256k.bin - it has seabios.bin. Linking seabions.bin and seabios-256k.bin work fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/share/qemu/bios.bin /usr/share/qemu/bios-256k.bin
```

and use

```
-L /usr/share/qemu/
```

in `qemu` command line if needed.